# Using Stripes, can I include the output resolution of an ActionBean into a jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, stripes

I have found a situation where I would like to include the same content on many pages by importing the output of an shared ActionBean.

What I would like to do is have an ActionBean which takes some parameters and does some processing and then returns a ForwardResolution to a JSP which renders the output of that ActionBean using standard Stripes constructs like `${actionBean.myValue`.

I would then like to "call" this ActionBean from other JSPs. This would have the effect of placing the output HTML from the first ActionBean into the Second JSP's output.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired result by using the `<jsp:include>` tag.

**SharedContentBean.java**

```
@UrlBinding("/sharedContent")
public class SharedContentBean implements ActionBean {

    String contentParam;

    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution view() {
        return new ForwardResolution("/sharedContent.jsp");
    }
}
```

**In your JSP**

```
<!-- Import Registration Form here -->
<jsp:include page="/sharedContent">
    <jsp:param value="myValue" name="contentParam"/>
</jsp:include>
```

**web.xml**

Make sure to add `INCLUDE` to your `<filter-mapping>` tag in web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Stripes has a very powerful layout mechanism if you find yourself doing this often. http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Layout+Reuse

Comment: Thanks. We use the Stripes Layout tags. In this case the component we wanted to import wasn't in a consistent location and we didn't want it on _every_ page, so I don't think the Stripes Layout structures would have helped this case. Its possible I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 1):

Have every ActionBean that you wish to contain the same content extend the same BaseAction and put the getters/setters in there.  For instance:

**BaseAction.class**

```
package com.foo.bar;

public class BaseAction implements ActionBean {

  private ActionBeanContext context;

  public ActionBeanContext getContext() { return context; }
  public void setContext(ActionBeanContext context) { this.context = context; }

  public String getSharedString() {
    return "Hello World!";
  }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
  <jsp:useBean id="blah" scope="page" class="com.foo.bar.BaseAction"/>
  <body>
    ${blah.sharedString}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is too-general a solution, and in this case, I wanted the HTML (jsp) to be external from the java code as well.

Comment: Updated JSP to reflect new changes in your requirements.

Comment: this solution doesn't fit well with returning complex information, for example, getSharedString() should be able to return the output of a jsp. This solution also isn't very IoC, since there may be a situation where an ActionBean requires multiple BaseAction beans. Sorry, I should have explained that in my previous comment.

Comment: "Multiple BaseAction beans" doesn't make any sense, as it's a BASE action bean that other action beans extend.  I'm afraid you're going to have to explain precisely what you are trying to accomplish if you expect to find help here.

Comment: If you have a single BaseAction bean, then you'll be exposing all your components globally. As I said, I want to be able to include HTML-widgets, not just raw text, into other pages. I already answered the question myself, feel free to see my SO answer for the correct solution.

Comment: You said you wanted the JSP to be external from the java code, yet you're forwarding to a JSP in your code.  Regardless, glad you found a solution.